# Abusing the `.Select` method to skip additional loops

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Assuming the following code where I need to load the navigational property attached to an entity (I have only faced this issue in EF Core and in EF 6 the Lazy load function works just fine)

```
ViewBag.DisplayTags = new String(query.ArticlesTags.SelectMany(x => {
                          db.Attach<EFContext.Database.ArticlesTags>(x).Navigation("Tag").Load();
                          return x.Tag.Name + ", ";
                       }).ToArray());
```

I'm attaching a collection to the EF tracker inside a select statement and then I'm loading a navigational property. I have done this to skip an additional for loop.

The question is that, although skipping another loop is an advantage (since select internally runs loops), would this approach cause any problem that is hidden from my view? Is there any downside? and is it even recommended?

Comment: How about looking into EF logs and getting to know what it is being traslated to?

Comment: @Karolis: I don't know how to that, can you please share any link on that?

Comment: I guess this would help regarding logging - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. You're going to run 1 query for every ArticlesTag in your database. So if you have 100 rows in the ArticlesTags table, the code above will sequentially run 101 queries against your database server (one extra for the direct query of ArticlesTags).

The following code will execute for every item in your list of ArticlesTags:

```
Navigation("Tag").Load();
```

That explicitly loads the Tag property on that single ArticlesTag by querying the database.

You could use a single Select statement to get all of the names from the db as a list and then join them using string.Join in memory. Something like

```
var names = db.ArticlesTags.Select(x => x.Tag.Name).ToArray();
var displayName = string.Join(", ", names);
```

Comment: I don't think so, because `ArticleTags` has been already loaded in the memory (by the previous query). That's why I tagged `Linq` too.

Comment: Corrected. It will issue 101 queries. The contents of your SelectMany will be executed for each ArticlesTag and will issue another query to the database

Comment: Well, I don't think the `SelectMany` in this case has anything to do with the database.

Comment: To clarify the expression is a Func<T,R> not Expression<Func<T,R>> in this case.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. SelectMany is executing in memory. And in each call to your delegate inside SelectMany you're issuing another query to the db when you call .Load

Comment: So what's the different between that and a foreach loop?

Comment: Your goal should be to issue one query to get back all the data you need (but no more than what you need) from your database, and then manipulate the results in memory so it's ready to display

Comment: There is no difference from a performance standpoint. Both are wrong

Comment: I downvoted because I think, this is not logical. In a for loop the same would happen.

Comment: And a join might introduce other problems, such as joining unwanted rows or redirecting more stress on the DB Server.

Comment: I think you're missing something on the fundamentals of data access. Good luck...

Comment: `ArticlesTags` is a list in memory, no query will be made to Db!

Comment: Issuing 100 queries to a database server instead of 1 is never the right answer

Comment: Load issues the subsequent queries. You don't understand what your code is actually doing

Comment: Jeff, that list is something preserved in memory, already loaded inside of the memory, why should there be any queries then??

Comment: I also think this is a bad move, but what you are explaining does not sound appropriate.

Comment: "Navigation("Tag").Load()" cannot be used, it shows not found error!

Comment: Updated answer. If the tag is null, it's because query.ArticlesTags represents an already materialized result set (not an IQueryable). I don't know where your query variable is defined but I updated the answer to be more explicit. I am commenting on the excerpt from your code where you use Navigation("Tags")

Comment: `Tag` is a navigation of ArticlesTags which is a collection. so you cannot load all Tags at once like that.

Comment: The right answer to this question is to give up EF and write a view instead. Because even if I wanna write a join in Linq, there will be too many joins which would be even worse than this.

Comment: And I give up on this. Using a view is fine but either way I'd suggest you do some reading on how EF works

Comment: Trust me I know a lot about EF, but the thing is that this navigation can be only and only loaded in a loop if I wanna do so in EF.

Comment: @Arrrr Jeff is right, you are doing it fundamentally wrong. Simple `Include` will do the same with 1 or 2 db queries.